# net472 vs net6.0: Default string sorting

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, net-4.7.2

I have this mini program:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFrameworks>net472;net6.0</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

internal static class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        var list = new List<string>()
        {
            "were",
            "we're",
            "weird",
        };

        foreach (var item in list.OrderBy(i => i))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
```

When compiled as `net472` I get

```
weird
were
we're
```

When I compile as `net6.0` I get

```
we're
weird
were
```

Is there a way to configure or determine what kind of sorting rule is applied by default?

**Edit:**

It is indeed, as [Alexander Petrov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5045688/alexander-petrov) said, the difference between [ICU and NLS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/globalization-icu)

Configuring the project file as such makes them both behave identically:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <RuntimeHostConfigurationOption Include="System.Globalization.UseNls" Value="true" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Are you running the two under the same locale settings?

Comment: @KristoferA compiled under Visual Studio at the same time in the same environment

Comment: This is probably due to the differences between NLS and ICU. See [.NET globalization and ICU](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/globalization-icu).

Comment: When using `UseNls`, then in .NET6 gets the same result as in .NET4.7.

Comment: @DeeJ.Doena keep in mind that .NET Core is cross-platform. If you use UseNls you'll end up with an unexpected sort when your code runs on Linux, eg if you deploy your web app using Docker or to a cloud provider

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for the info and this wasn't really productive code just one of my tools for private use which I converted to net6 for educational purposes when I stumbled over this difference and tried to understand what's behind it.